# How to customize contour line labels?

Tags: label, octave, contour

I would like to visualize a function of two variables in a contour plot using Octave, and to put customized line labels on it.

Building on the Octave documentation, I wrote:

```
clf;
colormap ("default");
[x, y, z] = peaks ();
subplot(2,1,1);
contour (x, y, z,'showtext', 'on');
title ({"contour() plot, showtext on"; "Z = peaks()"});
subplot(2,1,2);
[ctr, h] = contour (x, y, z);
cll = clabel(ctr, h, 'backgroundcolor',[1 1 1]);
title ({"contour() plot, using clabel()"; "Z = peaks()"});
```

[image: Two more or less identical plots produced by the code snippet above]

Which produces two only marginally (if at all) different plots. The labels are there, but don't look nice at all; I need better quality for this project.

What I would like to do is, in order of priority:

1. Show labels with 2 - 3 decimal digits only.
2. Change the label background to white.
3. Plot labels inline with the contour line.

From Octave documentation it appears that the label values are stored in `"userdata"`, but it's not of much help because:

```
>> get(cll, "userdata")
ans =
{
  [1,1] =  6.7459
  [2,1] =  5.4167
  [3,1] =  5.4167
  [4,1] =  4.0874
  [5,1] =  4.0874
  [6,1] =  2.7581
  [7,1] =  2.7581
  [8,1] =  2.7581
  [9,1] =  2.7581
  [10,1] =  1.4289
  [11,1] =  1.4289
  [12,1] =  1.4289
  [13,1] =  1.4289
  [14,1] =  0.099636
  [15,1] =  0.099636
  [16,1] =  0.099636
  [17,1] =  0.099636
  [18,1] =  0.099636
  [19,1] =  0.099636
  [20,1] = -1.2296
  [21,1] = -1.2296
  [22,1] = -1.2296
  [23,1] = -1.2296
  [24,1] = -2.5589
  [25,1] = -2.5589
  [26,1] = -2.5589
  [27,1] = -3.8881
  [28,1] = -5.2174
```

I am not sure how the number of repetitions for a value is determined.
I'd appreciate help on this matter.

Comment: That matches the number of times each value is shown -- longer lines can fit more labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show labels with fewer digits, the best way is to manually specify at which z-values to draw contour lines (see explanation in the documentation to [`contourc`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/contourc.html)):

```
colormap('default');
[x, y, z] = peaks();
vn = ceil(min(z(:))):floor(max(z(:))); % list of all integer values within range of data
contour(x, y, z, vn, 'showtext', 'on');
title({"contour() plot, showtext on"; "Z = peaks()"});
```

You can also specify which contour lines to put labels on:

```
colormap('default');
[x, y, z] = peaks();
vn = ceil(min(z(:))):floor(max(z(:)));
[ctr, h] = contour(x, y, z, vn);
clabel(ctr, h, vn(1:2:end), 'backgroundcolor',[1 1 1]);
title({"contour() plot, showtext on"; "Z = peaks()"});
```

I don't have Octave here, but the `'background color'` argument should do its thing. It is possible that the lines are drawn over the text, rather than the text over the lines. MATLAB has a command `uistack` to force drawing order, but this does not seem to exist in Octave. There, [one possibility](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/moving-graphic-objecs-td2997314.html) might be to change the order of the children of the axis object:

```
set(gca,'children',flip(get(gca,'children')))
```

(Note: MATLAB's `contour` does a better job of picking nice contour levels, and it also by default interrupts the line where the labels are, so lines and text don't intersect.)

Comment: Well, I used your suggestions and tinkered a bit more with my real data, to obtain this plot:

Answer (score 0):

Well, I used your suggestions and tinkered a bit more with my real data, to obtain this plot:

[image]

Which is good for my needs, except for that lonely "0.09" in the left part of the plot. That shouldn't be there but I cannot figure why it appears.

`set(gca,'children',flip(get(gca,'children')))` does not work tho.