# Octave on Linux: Cannot set Text Background Color for Labels

Tags: label, octave, contour

Connected to this question: [How to customize contour line labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53454873/how-to-customize-contour-line-labels)

I was experimenting - Octave 4.2.2 under Ubuntu 14.04.5 - with contour plot labels using this code:

```
x = 0:5;
y = x;
z = x' * y;
clf();
[c,h] = contour (x, y, z, 1:3);
cll = clabel(c, h, 1:3,
             'fontsize', 12,
             'fontweight', 'bold',
             'color', [1, 1, 1],
             'backgroundcolor', 'blue',
             'labelspacing', 72);
```

Which should produce labels in white text over a blue background. But in the resulting plot, there is no background:

[image: no background]

Moreover, the graphics property is properly set:

```
>> get(cll, "backgroundcolor")
ans =
{
  [1,1] =

     0   0   1

  [2,1] =

     0   0   1

  [3,1] =

     0   0   1

  [4,1] =

     0   0   1

  [5,1] =

     0   0   1

  [6,1] =

     0   0   1

  [7,1] =

     0   0   1

  [8,1] =

     0   0   1

  [9,1] =

     0   0   1

  [10,1] =

     0   0   1

  [11,1] =

     0   0   1

  [12,1] =

     0   0   1

  [13,1] =

     0   0   1

  [14,1] =

     0   0   1

  [15,1] =

     0   0   1

  [16,1] =

     0   0   1

  [17,1] =

     0   0   1

  [18,1] =

     0   0   1

  [19,1] =

     0   0   1

  [20,1] =

     0   0   1

}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you try changing the graphics backend? Octave has different options there, and they don’t all do everything correctly (in my experience, which is very limited).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the latest octave on my linux mint 18.3. Contour labels appear fine, white on blue squares.

Comment: Are you using the 'gnuplot' graphics_toolkit by any chance? Try switching to 'fltk' or 'qt'. The GUI version of octave should be using 'qt' by default ...

Comment: I have three graphics toolkit available: 'gnuplot', 'qt', and 'fltk'. They all produce the same result.

Comment: @Fabio, be sure to `close all` after switching the graphics_toolkit

Comment: Otherwise the plot will be done still with the previous graphics toolkit?

Comment: Even with `close all`, the result is the same.
@TasosPapastylianou, latest Octave meaning 4.4.1? Its release notes mention fixing graphics rendering, so maybe that's it.